# How to use $_GET in a string?

Tags: php

I have a simple PHP file with the following:

```
<?php
echo 'catid=$_GET["catid"]';
<?>
```

When I run the page, the output is:

```
catid=$_GET["catid"]
```

I'm accessing the page as www.abc.com/temp.php?catid=3.  I'd like $_GET to execute so I see:

```
catid=3
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nobody mentions it, but beware of xss injections, run a check before printing on the page an external input _as is_. Use htmlentities, or cast to int if it has to be an int, or make other checks.

Comment: @4thSpace please, don't take Damien's comment lightly. XSS injections may result in evil script tags being added to your HTML that, for example steals a users password or adds malware to your page if somebody sends them a specially crafted URL to your website

Comment: Are there any examples on how this can be handled for the above scenario?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_Get` is a variable, and to echo a variable you do not need parenthesis around it.

```
<?php
echo 'catid='.$_GET["catid"];
?>
```

please see this : [source](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_echo.asp)

Comment: Syntax error: unexpected token "<" on line 3 (or something like that)

Comment: Wow - so many answers so quickly.  I think this was first and I'll accept it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have to cancat the two:

```
echo 'catid=' . $_GET["catid"];
```

or you could use `"` (double quotes):

```
echo "catId=$someVar";
```

Comment: or even `echo "catId=$_GET[catid]";`

Comment: @showdev True that. I added this for completeness and simply used another variable. I can't even say why. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use non-array variables for that:

```
$getCatID = $_GET["catid"];
echo "catid=$getCatID";
```

Or you can use (recommended):

```
echo 'catid=' . $_GET["catid"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
echo "catid= {$_GET['catid']}";
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use variables in string is:

```
echo "catid={$_GET['catid']}";
```

Comment: Interesting. What makes that the best way?

Comment: because without braces you cant have some number preceding the variable value. for example if i wanted to have 0 . $_GET['catid'] i wouldnt be able to do it without braces

Comment: I'm not following. Seems to work fine [here](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/saf-miz).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use double quoted string to notify PHP that it might contains variables inside. $_GET is array, so you will need to put the variable statement in {}.

```
<?php
    echo "catid={$_GET['catid']}";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options to combine a variable with a string.

```
<?php

    $var = "something";

    // prints some something
    echo 'some ' . $var; // I prefer to go for this one

    // prints some something
    echo "some $var";

    // prints some $var
    echo 'some $var';

    // prints some something
    echo "some {$var}";

?>
```